# Notice: Undefined index: name, cannot insert data

Tags: php

another problem is here. i'm created insert data into database. Then, i got the error Notice: Undefined index: name on the line 252.. here is my code..below is form code..

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />

    <?php
        if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            //form not submitted
        }
        else
        {
            //get from input
            //escape input values for greater safety
            $name=(trim($_POST['name'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter name') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']); // line 252
            $address=(trim($_POSTname['address'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter Address') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['address']);
            $phone=(trim($_POST['phone'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter Phone') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
            $email=(trim($_POST['email'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter Email') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
            $item1=(trim($_POST['item1'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter Donut') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['item1']);
            $item2=(trim($_POST['item2'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter Donut') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['item2']);
            $item3=(trim($_POST['item3'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter Donut') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['item3']);
            $item4=(trim($_POST['item4'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter Donut') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['item4']);
            $item5=(trim($_POST['item5'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter Donut') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['item5']);

            //open connection
            $connection=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('Unable to connect');

            //select database
            mysql_select_db('donut') or die ('Unable to select database');

            //create query
            $query= "INSERT INTO ordering (name,address,phone,email,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5) VALUES ('$name','$address','$phone','$email', '$item1','$item2','$item3','$item4','$item5')";

            //execute query
            $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query.".mysql_error());

            //print ID of inserted record
            echo 'New record has been successfully inserted';

            //close connection
            mysql_close($connection);
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Well, this my form code.. can you see any error?

```
<td width="24%" class="n"><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
    <td width="26%"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="n"><label for="address">Address:</label></td>
    <td><textarea name="address" id="address"></textarea></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="n"><label for="phone">Phone Number :</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="n"><label for="email">Email :</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="n"><label for="donut"> Choose Donut :</label></td>
    <td><p>
      <span class="k">
      <select name="item1" id="item1">
        <option>Colorful Choc </option>
        <option>Black Forest</option>
        <option>chezzy Gum</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        <option>Coconut Bead</option>
        <option>Cheese Gaeden</option>
        <option>Creamy Straw</option>
        <option>Stripe Donut</option>
        <option>Choc Sugar</option>
        <option>Chocolate Chip</option>
        <option>Pillow Choc</option>
        <option>Star Wars</option>
        <option>Regular</option>
        <option>Diamond Bead</option>
        <option>Strawberry</option>
        <option>Munchys</option>
        <option>Popcorn</option>
        <option>Berry Cheese</option>
        <option>Sugar Bread</option>
        <option>Choc Chopstick</option>
        <option>Regular Planta</option>
        <option>Round Round</option>
        <option>Sprinkle Nuts</option>
        <option>Sprinkle Color</option>
      </select>
      </span></p>
      <p>
        <span class="k">
        <select name="item2" id="item2">
          <option>Colorful Choc </option>
          <option>Black Forest</option>
          <option>chezzy Gum</option>
          <option>Orange</option>
          <option>Coconut Bead</option>
          <option>Cheese Gaeden</option>
          <option>Creamy Straw</option>
          <option>Stripe Donut</option>
          <option>Choc Sugar</option>
          <option>Chocolate Chip</option>
          <option>Pillow Choc</option>
          <option>Star Wars</option>
          <option>Regular</option>
          <option>Diamond Bead</option>
          <option>Strawberry</option>
          <option>Munchys</option>
          <option>Popcorn</option>
          <option>Berry Cheese</option>
          <option>Sugar Bread</option>
          <option>Choc Chopstick</option>
          <option>Regular Planta</option>
          <option>Round Round</option>
          <option>Sprinkle Nuts</option>
          <option>Sprinkle Color</option>
        </select>
      </span></p>
      <p>
        <span class="k">
        <select name="item3" id="item3">
          <option>Colorful Choc </option>
          <option>Black Forest</option>
          <option>chezzy Gum</option>
          <option>Orange</option>
          <option>Coconut Bead</option>
          <option>Cheese Gaeden</option>
          <option>Creamy Straw</option>
          <option>Stripe Donut</option>
          <option>Choc Sugar</option>
          <option>Chocolate Chip</option>
          <option>Pillow Choc</option>
          <option>Star Wars</option>
          <option>Regular</option>
          <option>Diamond Bead</option>
          <option>Strawberry</option>
          <option>Munchys</option>
          <option>Popcorn</option>
          <option>Berry Cheese</option>
          <option>Sugar Bread</option>
          <option>Choc Chopstick</option>
          <option>Regular Planta</option>
          <option>Round Round</option>
          <option>Sprinkle Nuts</option>
          <option>Sprinkle Color</option>
        </select>
      </span></p>
      <p>
        <span class="k">
        <select name="item4" id="item4">
          <option>Colorful Choc </option>
          <option>Black Forest</option>
          <option>chezzy Gum</option>
          <option>Orange</option>
          <option>Coconut Bead</option>
          <option>Cheese Gaeden</option>
          <option>Creamy Straw</option>
          <option>Stripe Donut</option>
          <option>Choc Sugar</option>
          <option>Chocolate Chip</option>
          <option>Pillow Choc</option>
          <option>Star Wars</option>
          <option>Regular</option>
          <option>Diamond Bead</option>
          <option>Strawberry</option>
          <option>Munchys</option>
          <option>Popcorn</option>
          <option>Berry Cheese</option>
          <option>Sugar Bread</option>
          <option>Choc Chopstick</option>
          <option>Regular Planta</option>
          <option>Round Round</option>
          <option>Sprinkle Nuts</option>
          <option>Sprinkle Color</option>
        </select>
      </span></p>
      <p>
        <span class="k">
        <select name="item5" id="item5">
          <option>Colorful Choc </option>
          <option>Black Forest</option>
          <option>chezzy Gum</option>
          <option>Orange</option>
          <option>Coconut Bead</option>
          <option>Cheese Gaeden</option>
          <option>Creamy Straw</option>
          <option>Stripe Donut</option>
          <option>Choc Sugar</option>
          <option>Chocolate Chip</option>
          <option>Pillow Choc</option>
          <option>Star Wars</option>
          <option>Regular</option>
          <option>Diamond Bead</option>
          <option>Strawberry</option>
          <option>Munchys</option>
          <option>Popcorn</option>
          <option>Berry Cheese</option>
          <option>Sugar Bread</option>
          <option>Choc Chopstick</option>
          <option>Regular Planta</option>
          <option>Round Round</option>
          <option>Sprinkle Nuts</option>
          <option>Sprinkle Color</option>
        </select>
      </span></p></td>
    <td><p class="k">T</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="n">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: BTW, if you *really* want to keep using `mysql_*` functions, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string`, `mysql_escape_string` is not safe enough.

Comment: If you show where is line 252, that would be great

Comment: @Wagner i already show it, please check it.. :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. "Undefined index" generally is about item not received from your $_POST, you could print all $_POST variables to see if you are getting all of them correctly

Comment: Like @Wagner said, do a `print_r($_POST)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ONE possible (*and most likely*) error is this line:

```
$address=(trim($_POSTname['address'])
```

which should read as:

```
$address=(trim($_POST['address'])
```

---

### EDIT example

Here is what I tried on my own server with success:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
<input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>

<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    //form not submitted
    }
    else
    {
    //get from input
    //escape input values for greater safety
    $name=(trim($_POST['name'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter name') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']); // line 252
    
    echo $name;
}
?>
```

You can also try the reverse:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
<input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    //get from input
    //escape input values for greater safety
    $name=(trim($_POST['name'])=='')? die ('ERROR : Enter name') : mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']); // line 252
    }
    else
    {
die("You cannot do that from here.");
}

echo $name;

?>
```

Comment: Good spot, though that looks more like a copy-paste error, because the error message would be different (and pointing to a different location).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel The OP did post that for code, so if it is in fact "that", then good. If not, well then, I'm baffled at what else it could be.

Comment: emm, i fix the code, but still have an error..

Comment: @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan The same error being what, `undefined index` ? Make 100% sure that your input fields match your SQL. Spelling errors, letter-case. `Name` is not the same as `name`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-yup, undefined index:name

Comment: As I stated above, make sure that your DB column field matches your `<input type="text" name="name">` - `Name` and `name` are NOT the same. Letter case is important. @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan

Comment: You mean variable names, like `$_POST['name']`, etc. You can give column fields any name, as long as your queries match (but that would result in a totally different error message).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Yes I agree, am just trying to see if the OP does in fact have that for code. So many times have I seen OPs posting code which wasn't what he/she was using.

Comment: i'm still figuring out what happen actually, check on my spelling, well thanks for the advice

Comment: @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan Then still post your markup and code AS IS and do a `print_r($_POST)` so you can see what *is* in `$_POST`.

Comment: @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan Another thing I spotted is your `</form>` being at the end. Try placing it underneath `<input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />` it shouldn't belong there.

Comment: @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan Did you do as I suggested about `</form>` in my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818674/notice-undefined-index-name-cannot-insert-data#comment29467870_19818903) just above?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i did..

Comment: You can't have `<form>....<?php // ... ?></form>` @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan

Comment: @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan And did you upload/update/reload/refresh and cleared your cache?

Comment: @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan Well, how do you know if it works or not then? Plus you may also want to use `('" . $name ."', '" . $address ."', '" . $phone . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $item1 . "', '" . $item2 . "', '" . $item3 . "', '" . $item4 . "', '" . $item5 . "')` instead of what you presently have.

Comment: It won't work until you uploaded them to your server and reload the page. @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan

Comment: @Fred-ii-i'm running on localhost now, yes i'm sorry, i already refresh the page, but still the same error

Comment: Instead of doing `if(!isset($_POST['submit']))` with your else, try it the other way around and use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` then your `$name=(trim($_POST['name'])=='') etc.` then after all that, use your `else` condition with a `die()` that's all I can think of. This should be working. @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan

Comment: I tested what I could with part of your code, and it worked for me. So, there's obviously something else going on here, that's not in your posted code. May not be relevant but I'll ask anyway; is `short tags` set to "ON"? I doubt that will make a difference. @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan

Comment: @Fred-ii-to much thinking today, can you give one example..what i should place on the else statement using die() statement? -,-

Comment: @Fred-ii-i think my DB is ok, nothing wrong... i don't know what the problem is..

Comment: @Fred-ii- where i can see the short tag is on?

Comment: @Fred-ii-yeah it's on

Comment: Ok. I added a few examples in an edit. Reload this page to see them. @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan

Answer (score 1):

Your **`<form>`** does not have an input field named "**`name`**" which you have used it here

```
trim($_POST['name'])=='')
```

Fix :

Add an input field on your form like this..

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
      <input type="text" name="name" /><!-- Added here -->
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
      <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
```

You are also missing other fields like phone , contact , email , etc....

Comment: im not posting all the code actually, the input field for name,contact and etc exist

Comment: @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan Then please post your full form and relevant parts of your code.

Comment: the code is here.. <tr>
    <td width="24%" class="n"><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
    <td width="26%"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

Comment: *"the input field for name,contact and etc exist"* - Oh, really? Could've fooled me. @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan

Comment: @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan Please edit your original question, don't put (lots of) code and markup in comments.

Comment: I may very well have found the error. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19818903/1415724) @MohamadNoorQusyairiManlan

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good idea to check whether a variable exists or not using [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) or [`empty`](http://php.net/empty). Even if one variable, e.g. `$_POST['submit']`, is present, that doesn't guarantee that other ones are present, too.

```
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    …
}
```